# How to benchmark internet connection speed, but not just top download speed of one big file?

Tags: internet-speed

I'm not sure if there's a term for what I'm looking for, but I'm not talking about just connectivity or just testing speed here.

When I was on cable, webpages virtually always loaded very quickly.  A few months back we switched to Verizon Fios and at first it was great.  Now we still have much faster upload and download speeds than we did with cable, however I often wait several seconds for a webpage to simply load.  Between having webpages load immediately and being able to download big files quicker I would generally choose to have snappier load times because I spend a lot more time loading pages then I do downloading big files.

After complaining, Verizon came out and did something that helped (they said it had something to do with two boxes being too close to each other and they moved them further apart).  However, the load speed of the average page is definitely still not what I expect it to be.  I don't know how to show them that there is a problem though.  If I go to do a speed test it's going to look fine.  Are there any other utilities I can use to benchmark other aspects of connection speed besides just the top download speed of a single big file?

EDIT:  Thought I should point out that just a few days ago I was trying to access a computer in my house using remote desktop from another computer in the same house.  The connection kept pausing momentarily... it never totally disconnected but for connecting to another computer just one room over it definitely should have been a much better connection.  So I was inclined to think the issue had something to do with the router that Verizon provided us.  However, they sent me a new one and it didn't fix the issue so I don't know.

EDIT2: I might not have made the problem sound as bad as it really is.  In addition to pages often taking longer than I feel they should take to load, they often just don't load until I close the tab and try again in a new one.